# Possible to make a producer/consumer obj in Scala using actors 'threadless' (no receive...)?

Tags: scala, actor

So I want to write some network code that *appears* to be blocking, without actually blocking a thread.  I'm going to send some data out on the wire, and have a 'queue' of responses that will come back over the network.   I wrote up a *very* simple proof of concept, inspired by the producer/consumer example on the actor tutorial found here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242

The thing is, using receive appears to take up a thread, and so I'm wondering if theres anyway to not take up a thread and still get the 'blocking feel'.  Heres my code sample:

```
import scala.actors.Actor._;
import scala.actors.Actor;

case class Request(val s:String);

case class Message(val s:String);

class Connection  {
  private val act:Actor = actor {
     loop {
      react {
        case m:Message =>  receive { case r:Request => reply { m } }
      } 
    }
}

  def getNextResponse(): Message = {
    return (act !? new Request("get")).asInstanceOf[Message];
  }

  //this would call the network layer and send something over the wire
  def doSomething() {
    generateResponse();
  }

  //this is simulating the network layer getting some data back 
  //and sending it to the appropriate Connection object
  private def generateResponse() {
   act ! new Message("someData");
   act ! new Message("moreData");    
   act ! new Message("even more data");
  }

}


object runner extends Application {
 val conn = new Connection(); 
    conn.doSomething();
    println( conn.getNextResponse());
    println(conn.getNextResponse());
    println(conn.getNextResponse());
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using the receive, and thereby making it threadless?

Answer (score 4):

You could directly rely on `react` which should block **and** release the thread:

```
class Connection  {
  private val act:Actor = actor {
    loop {
      react {
        case r:Request => reply { r }
      } 
    }
  }
[...]
```

Answer (score 3):

I expect that you can use react rather than receive and not have actors take up threads like receive does. There is thread on this issue at [receive vs react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251666/scala-actors-receive-vs-react).